# multiple payments usind single PaymentIntentCreateOptions

Tags: .net, stripe-payments

I am currently using stripe connect. My PaymentIntentCreateOptions looks like this

```
chargeOptions = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
                {
                    PaymentMethodId = parameter.Token,
                    Amount = parameter.Amount,
                    Currency = "USD",
                    Description = "Transaction charge for something",
                    Confirm = true,
                    ConfirmationMethod = "manual",
                    StatementDescriptor = "xyz.com",
                    ApplicationFeeAmount = applicationFeeAmount,
                    TransferData = new PaymentIntentTransferDataOptions
                    {
                        Destination = parameter.StripeConnectAccountID,
                    },
                };
```

what i am hoping is to do multiple payouts on stripe using single PaymentIntentCreateOptions. I am wondering if that is possible. Since my transaction has products from multiple merchants, I dont want to call stripe again and again for each merchant. Rather than pass all the data in one go to stripe API and let it handle the payouts. So something like this

chargeOptions = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions

```
{
{
                        PaymentMethodId = parameter.Token,
                        Amount = parameter.Amount,
                        Currency = "USD",
                        Description = "Transaction charge for something",
                        Confirm = true,
                        ConfirmationMethod = "manual",
                        StatementDescriptor = "xyz.com",
                        ApplicationFeeAmount = applicationFeeAmount,
                        TransferData = new PaymentIntentTransferDataOptions
                        {
                            Destination = parameter.**StripeConnectAccountID01**,
                        },
                    },
{
                        PaymentMethodId = parameter.Token,
                        Amount = parameter.Amount,
                        Currency = "USD",
                        Description = "Transaction charge for something",
                        Confirm = true,
                        ConfirmationMethod = "manual",
                        StatementDescriptor = "xyz.com",
                        ApplicationFeeAmount = applicationFeeAmount,
                        TransferData = new PaymentIntentTransferDataOptions
                        {
                            Destination = parameter.**StripeConnectAccountID02**,
                        },
                    }
};
```

Comment: No, one PaymentIntent maps to one successful payment. So you need to create multiple independent PaymentIntents here. But if you have a 'multi-basket' setup like this you should probably look into https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers instead, where you do one large PaymentIntent, and then separately transfer the funds out to multiple different accounts.

Comment: thanks i ll checkout now.